# Running local client and service on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to set up a client and a separate service to handle the requests locally with eclipse.  I have two WARS deployed to my Tomcat server.  My issue is that I am trying to link to an API in the service from the client and I cannot figure out how.  I tried putting in the full path as well as just the API but both autofill with the client's package (i.e. localhost/{clientName}/{API} rather than localhost/{serviceName}/{API}.  Any idea how to resolve this?  Code is below

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="location.href='http://localhost/messagingservice/login'"/>


@RestController
public class LoginServlet {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean login(String login, String password) {
        System.out.println("Hit login mapping");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running on port 80, and not 8080 (default)?

Comment: Yes I think I am.  Is that an issue?  This is from server.xml

    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

Comment: If you try to connect to the wrong port; yes. But it seems you are ok, though. Is it possible to eliminate Eclipse from the equation here, eg. run the service in a standalone tomcat, and use a standalone browser to connect to the service, to see if that works? Are there any hints in the tomcat log?